# Screen coordinates and view position

Tags: android, view, position, coordinates

my screen is 1080X1920 and as I know the right top corner of the screen coordinates are(0,0) and the left bottom corner is (Max,Max).
I use a relative layout which has a FAB at the right bottom corner.
When I click the FAB I create new FAB and try to set it's X and y to (0,0) and it appears in the right top corner instead of the left corner.
When I try to set it's position to (100,500) it appears out of the screen in the right side of the screen.

That is my code (the code is in a function in another class,context defines as this,l is the relativelayout)

```
FloatingActionButton bt;
bt = new FloatingActionButton(context);
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    bt.setX(0);
    bt.setY(0);
    bt.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(height, height));
        l.addView(bt);
```

Comment: First of all, the top LEFT corner usually is 0,0 and the bottom RIGHT corner is (max, max). 

As for your question, try adding the layoutParams first THEN setting its x and y to 0 (setLayoutParams -> setX, setY -> addView). By setting new layout params you are overwriting any other layout params the view already has, thus overwriting your setX(0) and setY(0) commands.

Alternatively there can be issues with view gravity here, if you have set your parent view gravity to right for example, the view will be drawn on the right end of its parent, regardless of x and y

Comment: Changed the order of the code as you said and it still doesn't work. The parent view  gravity not defines

Comment: Could you add the contents of your layout file? By the way, if you add your view to a RelativeLayout, you should use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams instead of AbsListView.LayoutParams. You can only use the LayoutParams of the type of the parent layout, so in your case RelativeLayout.LayoutParams - Try changing the type of the layout params and see if it works.